# save an upload image in a folder without form

Tags: php, jquery, post, upload, image-uploading

I want to upload an image from an input, and save it in a folder (called 'photos').
In HTML, I have a simple input type file like this:

```
<input type="file" name="inputFile" id="inputFile" accept="image/jpeg, 
image/png">
<span>Scegli una foto</span>
<input id="Invia" type="button" value="Invia">
```

In Javascript, i used this AJAX call:

```
var myFormData = new FormData();
    myFormData.append($("#inputFile")[0].files[0]['name'], $("#inputFile")[0].files[0]);

$("#Invia").click(function (){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',               
            processData: false,
            contentType: false, 
            data: myFormData,
            url: "../api/photo.php",
            dataType : 'json',  
            success: function(jsonData){}
    });
});
```

In PHP, the '../api/photo.php' file is this:

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$destination= '../app/photos';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["inputFile"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["inputFile"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$destination/$name");
?>
```

But it doesn't work. I'm not an expert of POST method, so i don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: What is `myFormData` ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write it. I correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your append values... I Checked in my local with your Script and alter something like ajax-url and success message for my convenient This is my code Please Check and let me know:

```
    $("#Invia").click(function (){  
    var form = new FormData();
    var myFormData = document.getElementById('inputFile').files[0]; //get the file 
    if (myFormData) {   //Check the file is emty or not
        form.append('inputFile', myFormData); //append files
    }    
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',               
            processData: false,
            contentType: false, 
            data: form,
            url: "test1.php", //My reference URL
            dataType : 'json',  
            success: function(jsonData){
                if(jsonData == 1)
                    $('#img_msg').html("Image Uploaded Successfully");
                else
                    $('#img_msg').html("Error While Image Uploading");
            }
    });
});
```

You don't need to change your php file but, Double check your Folder path is correct for storing the Image...

Comment: i copied and pasted your solution, inserting my php file, but it doesn't work. Can i see your HTML and PHP?

Comment: Sorry! It's works! I was uploading a file too big... thanks!